# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"license_report"}):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou criando um menu de acesso a parte de relátorio de algumas funcionalidades do sistema, mas ao criar a controller de license_report, quando tento acessar pelo caminho "license_report_path"

Ele me apresenta esse erro **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"license_report"}):**

o meu **routes.rb** esta assim :

```
resources :license_report, only: [:index, :show]
```

A minha license_report_controller.rb está assim:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class LicenseReportController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_user
    before_filter :set_contractual_instrument, only: [:show]
  
  
    def index
        includes = [:cr_program, :highway]
        @contractual_instruments = CrContractualInstrument.includes(includes).order(:ic_number)
        @contractual_instruments = @contractual_instruments.select { |ci| ci.valid_inspections.any? }
    end
  
    def show
        @license = License.where("cr_contractual_instrument_id = #{params[:id]}")
        byebug

        respond_to do |format|
            byebug
            format.html do
              add_breadcrumb 'Relátorios de licenças', 'license_report_path'
            end
            format.pdf do
                byebug
              pdf = LicenseReportPDF.new(@license.map{|license| license.id})
              send_data pdf.render, filename: pdf_filename, type: 'application/pdf', disposition: :inline
            end
        end
    end
  
    private

    def set_contractual_instrument
      @contractual_instrument = CrContractualInstrument.find(params[:id])
    end
  
    def pdf_filename
      time = Time.current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S')
      name = @contractual_instrument.ic_number.gsub('/', '-')
  
      "#{name}_#{time}.pdf"
    end

end
```

Se eu retiro qualquer menção a **license_report_path** o código volta a funcionar normalmente.

Como faço para adicionar essa rota, sendo que ela deveria estar inclusa em resources ou estou pensando errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal é você deixar o controller pluralizado, ex: LicenseReports.

Daí quando vc colocar o resources nas rotas, ele vai criar as rotas para as actions, sendo a index:

```
license_reports_path
```

new:

```
new_license_report_path
```

edit:

```
edit_license_report_path
```

e as demais (show, update e destroy):

```
license_report_path
```

porém passando o parâmetro de busca (id), ex:

```
license_report_path(id: params[:id])
```

Não estando no plural pode vir a dar problemas como já aconteceu comigo

Comment: Lembrando que na action "edit" também é necessário passar o parâmetro

Answer (score 1):

isso acontece porque o license_report_path tem como parametro obrigatório o id se você fizer algo do tipo

```
license_report_path(params[:id])
```

ou

```
license_report_path(id: params[:id])
```

deve resolver.

Comment: Obrigado!! Deu certo, mas.. eu queria que ele entrasse sem parametro obrigatório e não consegui visualisar onde "setei" esse parametro como obrigatório.

Comment: o resources :license_report, only: [:show] que gera essa dependencia de um ID, para fazer um show sem essa dependencia, você pode usar o resource que ficará assim:

**resource :license_report, only: [:index, :show]**

ou deixar do modo mais rubocop

**resource :license_report, only: %i[index show]**